# How do I prove that this function is injective and surjective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Assume $f$ is a function such:
$$f: \omega\times\omega\to\omega$$
and
$$f (\langle x,y\rangle) = \frac{1}{2}\left[(x+y)^2+3x+y\right].$$
How do I prove that this function is one-to-one (injective) an also from $\omega\times\omega$ onto $\omega$ (surjective)?

In *Elements of Set Theory* by Herbert B. Enderton, there's an image of such one-to-one function that is also from $\omega\times\omega$ onto $\omega$.

[image]

Actually I don't now how to verify that this function is a one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are the definitions of injectivity and surjectivity? Usually you start from there and then it's pretty straight forward. And it might be useful to know what $\omega$ is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints.

**Proving well-definedness**

Before we can start thinking about injectivity and surjectivity, we should first prove that this function is well-defined. That is, given natural numbers $x$ and $y$, we should check that $f(\langle x,y \rangle)$ is in fact a natural number. The $\frac{1}{2}$ that appears in the definition of $f$ is alarming. In order for $f(\langle x,y \rangle)$ to be a natural number, we need $(x+y)^2 + 3x +y$ to be an even natural number. Why is this the case?

**Basic algebra is not enough to prove bijectivity**

The tricky thing about this function is that it is not injective when regarded as a function $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. (For example, we have $f(\langle 0, 1 \rangle) = 1 = f(\langle \frac{-3 + \sqrt{17}}{2}, 0 \rangle).$)

So, at least for proving injectivity, we will have to resort to some combinatorial or number theoretic property of the natural numbers—basic algebraic manipulations will not be enough.

**Using the picture**

It is clear that the function shown in the picture is bijective. So, if we can show that $f$ is the function shown in the picture, we will be done.

First, we observe that the function shown in the picture is $\langle x,y \rangle \mapsto T_{x+y} + (x+1) - 1$, where $T_n$ denotes the $n$th [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). This is true because the points enumerated by $f(\langle 0, 0 \rangle), f(\langle 0, 1 \rangle) , f(\langle 1, 0 \rangle), f(\langle 0, 2 \rangle) \dots, f(\langle x,y \rangle)$ form a triangle of side length $x+y$ plus a row of length $x+1$ and because the enumeration starts at $0$.

There is a nice formula for the triangular numbers that can be obtained by induction. Once you have obtained this formula, you can use simple algebra to show that $f(\langle x,y \rangle) = T_{x+y+1} + (x+1) - 1$.